# Java: Trigger JAAS authentication without security-constraint in web.xml

Tags: java, rest, authentication, jboss, jaas

I am having issues regarding authentication in Java EE. Let me introduce by saying which technologies I am using:
- Jboss AS 7.1
- JAAS Database login module
- RESTeasy

I will try to organize my problem like this:

**Behaviour I know it works:**
I specify "/index.html" as a protected resource in my web.xml file and specify security domain in my "jboss-web.xml" file. Access to "index.html" redirects the user to the "login.html" form page. The submit form of this page works with "j_security_check" and the container does the authentication properly. If I call a REST service that gets "request.getPrincipal()" I successfully obtain principal information. Also, access to another protected resource is validated because user is logged. Everything OK.

**Behaviour I would like to have (I tried but something is missing):**
I want to be able to invoke login.html and submit the action to a login method in a REST service. This rest service will invoke login method (right now I am using request.login(username,password)) and do the login process. In subsequent calls to different REST services, req.getPrincipal() would obtain the credentials for the logged user.

**Problems with the desired behaviour:**
After I invoke login method in my REST service, login works good, but next time I try to get principal information from request or SecurityContext class, it is null. And if I try to access a protected resource (let's say, another html) container does not recognize that user is logged.
It looks like login "manually" without having requested any protected resources in advance does not trigger authentication mechanism in the container, because after I do this "manual login", the next time I call request.getPrincipal() is completely null and I cannot obtain principal information for requesting personalized information from my business services.

**Why I want to do this:**
The purpose for achieving this behaviour is that **I don't want to rely authentication to a  whole html page**, but to have a small login form embebbed in other page that calls authentication mechanism in the container. But yes, if somebody tries to access a protected resource inside the application, I want to redirect the action to a login form page.

Everything that you may respond will be tremendously helpful, thanks in advance.

Diego